# Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:

Tags: r, github

I am trying to install `shinytableau`, but keep failing. How to get around this error? many thanks in advance.

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/shinytableau")
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 403.
  API rate limit exceeded for .... (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)

  Rate limit remaining: 0/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2022-09-10 18:08:49 UTC

  To increase your GitHub API rate limit
  - Use `usethis::create_github_token()` to create a Personal Access Token.
  - Use `usethis::edit_r_environ()` and add the token as `GITHUB_PAT`.
```

Comment: I've never seen that, but for once I think that error message is pretty clear: for some reason, you have reached your rate limit for unauthenticated github API hits. Have you tried the two `usethis::` expressions? If not, have you waited some time (10 minutes, an hour, I don't know) and tried again? Is your public IP there (`84.4.158.65`) shared among many users, knowingly or otherwise?

Comment: otherwise. many thanks.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.